# Sql Joining two tables and fetching a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables 'talent_empcomp' and 'talent_employee_details_v' where i need to fetch a value from 'Emp_Compensation' which is present only in 'talent_empcomp' table but 'Emp_Id' is common in both tables and has same values..i need to fetch 'Emp_Compensation' for a perticular 'Emp_Id'
below is the joint query iam running ..but iam getting an error message "Column 'Emp_Id' in where clause is ambiguous"

```
SELECT A.*, B.Emp_Compensation 
FROM talent_employee_details_v A, talent_empcomp B   
WHERE Emp_FirstName like '%' and Emp_Id='$Emp_Id' ORDER BY Emp_FirstName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use explicit join syntax.  Second you should use the table aliases you define:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Emp_Compensation
FROM talent_employee_details_v A join
     talent_empcomp B
     on a.EmpId = B.Emp_id
WHERE A.Emp_FirstName like '%' and A.Emp_Id='$Emp_Id'
ORDER BY A.Emp_FirstName
```

It is a good idea to put aliases before column references so you know where the values are coming from.  I am guessing the names are from "A".

Comment: Thanks for everyone who has replied for this question,, i have checked all of your answers all answers works fine....

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to filter of the `Emp_Id` column, but it is present in both tables, so the SQL interpreter does not know which column to filter. You need to explicitly qualify the column like `B.Emp_Id`.

```
SELECT A.*, B.Emp_Compensation 
FROM talent_employee_details_v A, talent_empcomp B   
WHERE Emp_FirstName like '%' and B.Emp_Id='$Emp_Id' ORDER BY Emp_FirstName
```

By the way: Your query might run faster if you remove the `like %` condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, B.Emp_Compensation 
FROM talent_employee_details_v A, talent_empcomp B   
WHERE Emp_FirstName like '%' and B.Emp_Id='$Emp_Id' ORDER BY Emp_FirstName
```

Comment: People really do enjoy explanations :-)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you run a join and have not specified which table to select the column from. All it takes is to specify the table before the column name, like A.Emp_id